# Try Catch showing more than what I expect

Tags: vb.net

I"m using a TRY Catch Block and the error i get and expect lands here:

```
       Throw New System.Exception("Copy of FileZilla file failed: " & ex.Message)
```

The output I get and in the following order is:

Create of FileZilla folder failed: 
   Create of FileZilla file failed: 
   Copy of FileZilla file failed: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server' is denied.

Why does it hit the other 2 and display them as well?

```
        Dim sourceFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(strSourcePathAndFile)

        Try
            ' Create the folder if it does not exist.
            If Not Directory.Exists(strDestinationFolder) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strDestinationFolder)
            End If

            Try
                ' Create the file if it does not exist.
                If Not File.Exists(strDestinationPathAndFile) Then
                    File.Create(strDestinationPathAndFile)
                End If
                Try
                    ' Copy the source file to the destination file and overwrite it.
                    sourceFile.CopyTo(strDestinationPathAndFile, True)
                Catch ioex As IOException
                    Throw New System.Exception("Copy of FileZilla file I/O failed: " & ioex.Message)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw New System.Exception("Copy of FileZilla file failed: " & ex.Message)
                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New System.Exception("Create of FileZilla file failed: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New System.Exception("Create of FileZilla folder failed: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Regards...

Comment: If you `throw` the error, it will be **THROWN** to the next catch block.

Comment: because you're using nested `Try..catch` block. The error is being `catch` by the parent ones.

Comment: New to this....This method can potentially fail in anyone of the actions so I want  to send to the UI a message that defines where it failed. So I thought the THROW NEW was the way to do it there by attaching the the text as to where in the method it is failing. So then what's the correct construct to get just the 1 section to be passed?

Comment: Should these not be nested? If I do not nest, is the behavior of the try catch after it catches to go the the end of the method and not execute the other actions?

Answer (score 2):

Because you Throw New exception, it gets caught by another Catch block, rinse & repeat.

Your outer handlers handle generic Exception type, maybe that's what you are asking for. Change it to handle other types of exceptions instead. Or just have one Try...Catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching three thrown exceptions, because you have three levels of Try... Catch.

What else were you expecting?

The Inner-most Catch throws a new exception.  This is naturally caught by the middle Catch, which then throws a new exception, which is caught by the outermost catch.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using nested `try..catch` block. The error is being `catch` at several levels. You can try the following instead:

```
Dim sourceFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(strSourcePathAndFile)
Dim error as String

    Try
        ' Create the folder if it does not exist.
        If Not Directory.Exists(strDestinationFolder) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strDestinationFolder)
        End If

        Try
            ' Create the file if it does not exist.
            If Not File.Exists(strDestinationPathAndFile) Then
                File.Create(strDestinationPathAndFile)
            End If
            Try
                ' Copy the source file to the destination file and overwrite it.
                sourceFile.CopyTo(strDestinationPathAndFile, True)

            Catch ioex As IOException

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) then _
                error = string.concat("Copy of FileZilla file I/O failed: ", ioex.Message)
            Catch ex As Exception

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) then _
                error = string.concat("Copy of FileZilla file failed: ", ex.Message)
            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) then _
            error = string.concat("Create of FileZilla file failed: ", ex.Message)
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New System.Exception(string.concat(error, ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi...I tried the code above....but now it does not catch the error and because of it, it goes to another error down stream. If I put the original code back, it catches it..albeit with the additional  messages I'm trying to not have display. Your logic seems solid so I don't get it.

Comment: @user3020047 Please post solutions to your question as their own answer rather than editing them into answers.

Comment: Hi..I don't have a solution yet. I was trying to show this person what I had done per his suggestion. The system would not accept the volume. So how/where do i post that in response to this specific user?

Comment: @user3020047 so you want to get the inner-most error message, right? Ok i'll edit the solution for you.. Can you retry please?